# Running automated tests in client machine

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, running-other-programs

Basically my requirement is :

I have developed a framework using selenium webdriver,maven and testng for a application under test.

Now i have to pass that on to the client without sharing the source code ..so that if he wants he can run the test in his machine without having everything else installed ..except java. and the output should be stored in one of the specific folders of the client machine.

Can i use any plugin in maven which will store the result or copy the result file to any folder of client machine.?

Please guide me how to achieve this.. how to pass on the above to client so that test run smoothly in his machine .

is there anything i need to take care while am using maven in the project?
I am using chrome browser to run the tests..
The application under test is available to be accessed from any type of browser.

kindly suggest.

Comment: You need to create a jar, including all dependencies. Maven has plugins for that. Once you pass that off to your client, I am almost certain there will only be additional problems! What is the issue with sharing source with the client?

Comment: @SiKing Am not certain about the issue in sharing the source code but the manager asked me to do this.. so i am trying to find  way.  Can you please give some aspects of the problems that it may create at client side..if i create this jar and send?

Comment: Create the jar, and try it from **several** different machines at your office first!